# Increase vertical space between inference rules

Tags: beamer, semantics

I am using the `semantic` package with `beamer` to make some inference rules for a language. There are about 10 relatively small-sized rules and I want them to be all in one slide. However, the rules are so piled up that the slide is hardly readable. Is it possible to increase the vertical space between them?

```
\makeatletter\let\ifGm@compatii\relax\makeatother
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{semantic}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Frame}
  $\inference[Bracketing]{X:\theta}{(X):\theta}$
  $\inference[Zero]{}{0:\textbf{val}[\textbf{nat}]}$
  $\inference[Succ]{N:\textbf{val}[\textbf{nat}]}{succ N:\textbf{val}[\textbf{nat}]}$
  $\inference[Truth]{}{\textbf{true}:\textbf{val}[\textbf{bool}]}$
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add some vertical space between the semantic rules:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{semantic}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Frame}

$\inference[Bracketing]{X:\theta}{(X):\theta}$

\bigskip

$\inference[Zero]{}{0:\textbf{val}[\textbf{nat}]}$

\bigskip

$\inference[Succ]{N:\textbf{val}[\textbf{nat}]}{succ N:\textbf{val}[\textbf{nat}]}$

\bigskip

$\inference[Truth]{}{\textbf{true}:\textbf{val}[\textbf{bool}]}$
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

An `itemize` list might also help.

[image]